# Adding up terms working with for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, python-3.x, equation

Compute the natural logarithm , by adding up to n terms in the series `1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + 1/5 -... 1/n` where n is a positive integer and input by user.

My problem seems to be in the  equation.  Or rather I dont know how to enter it to add all integers of the input and not just 1 or 2.

```
def LogEquation(n)
  n = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
  for n in range (1, n+1):
      log = 1 - 1/n + 1/n+1
  print (log)


LogEquation() //function called
```

Comment: Since you are using python3, i dont think it is the issue with integer division. Rather, I think the issue is, `1/n+1` is being interpreted as `(1/n) + 1` rather than `1/(n+1)`

Comment: `1/n = 0` for any `integer n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your formula is wrong - you are always just computing the last two terms in your loop - try this, you need to ensure you always add something to log. Also you are using 'n' for two different things - your input variable and for your loop - it is not good practice.

```
def LogEquation():
   n = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
   log = 0 

   sgn = +1 # Do we add or subtract

   for a in range (1, n+1):
      log = log + sgn * 1.0/a # Use 1.0 so we do floating point arithmetic
      sgn = -sgn # We added the last term - so subtract the next

   print (log)

LogEquation()
```

Comment: This could do with more explanation of the changes (e.g. the loop variable) and note that the parameter `n` is pointless.

Comment: n is not pointless - it is what the OP uses to define the precision of the calculation

Comment: ...and it's immediately replaced by user input.

Comment: I am not sure what this series calculates - but it doesn't calculate the natural logarithm I don't think.

Comment: what is  `sgn = +1 `?

Comment: sgn is a variable to keep track of wether you add or subtract the next value from the loop - if you look at your formula you alternate between add and subtract.

Comment: My bad - this seems to calculate ln(2) - i.e. the natural log of 2 - although it converges very slowly - several hundred terms to get the first two decimal points.

Comment: I still don't get what `sgn = +1`  is supposed to do

Comment: it assigns the value of +1 to the name sgn - you could just use sgn = 1 - but I prefer +1 in this case to make it explicit - especially for the OP.